# asp.net mvc editing the auto templates TT

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

im using dataAnnotation and meta data for my model classes all all is good
however i dont like that it creates an untidy form, and would rather it comes out in a nice
table i have set a style for so i have labels next to my inputs etc.

now there was a post somewhere that they are created from TT files and that you can set MVC to run from custom TT files but how do i do this ???  anyone got a link to the post somewhere.

many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locations and walk-through:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee291528.aspx